# Retrieving Gtk::Widget's relative position: get_allocation() doesn't work

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I need to retrieve the position of a `Gtk::Widget` relative to its parent, a `Gtk::Table`. Most sources (e.g. http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-faq/stable/x642.html) say that one needs to call `Gtk::Widget::get_allocation()`. However, the returned `Gtk::Allocation` object always contains `x = -1`, `y = -1`, `width = 1`, `height = 1`.

I have to note that this happens before the `Gtk::Table` object is actually exposed and rendered. A call to `show_all_children()` or `check_resize()`, which I would expect to recalculate child widget geometry, doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work after it got drawn?

Comment: Indeed it does. But the function that generates the `Gtk::Table` object has extra context, and it would be troublesome to, say, re-implement `on_expose_event()` and rescan all children to get and process this information.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `gtk_widget_realize()` on the top-level GtkTable.

Another approach, as suggested in the documentation I linked, is to attach a handler to the `GtkWidget::expose-event` signal.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Besides, `Gtk::Widget::realize()` is class-protected in the C++ API. So I guess I will have to delay the work until the `expose` event is delivered.